# Duplicate characters when opening typescript files in vim inside a tmux session

Tags: vim, tmux

[image: My code editor bug]

**Context**

I am using my work server (ubuntu 16.04) as my coding environment. Whenever I open up a typescript file (`.ts`), I get a strange rendering issue that makes it hard for me to code. Looking at the picture above, there is (incorrectly) two `c` and a character `a` from the variable name is missing.

What could be the issue?

**Expected code** - `const storeData = ...`

**Current display** - `cconst storeDat  = ...`

**My setup**

- Server - Ubuntu 16.04
- Tmux - `tmux next-3.3`
- Vim - `8.2.1767`

When I open the files in the terminal (not in a tmux session), it renders nicely

[image]

**What I tried**

- The only thing that made sense to me is set the tmux color, which I did in `~/.tmux.conf`:

  ```
  set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon looking at the differences between the 2 images, I suspected it may be because of unsupported `utf-8` issue. So I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410048/utf-8-character-not-showing-properly-in-tmux) which suggested setting environment variables:

```
export LC_ALL=en_IN.UTF-8
export LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
```

And it turns out I did not have the `UTF-8` language pack, so I was getting [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue):

```
warning: Setting locale failed.
```

To fix that, I installed the language pack as suggested in the answer:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en
```

Now the main issue is fixed! I no longer see the bad display as posted in the original question.

---

**BEWARE** - Before forcing `tmux` into `utf-8`, make sure you backup your tmux sessions. In doing these steps, I lost all my existing tmux sessions and I could not connect to them. I got the error below:

```
open terminal failed: can't find terminfo database
```

To fix the issue I had to stop the tmux server and then recreate the previously existing sessions.

```
tmux kill-server
```